# webpack.ProvidePlugin not work when the key is same to the module's name

Tags: javascript, webpack

```
// the key same to the value, it is not worked! return an empty object {}.
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   'angular': 'angular'
});

// not same, it is worked!
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'ng': 'angular'
});
```

and there is noting about the key can not the same to the module's name in the office [doc](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin).

Comment: "not worked" is not a helpful error description.

Answer (score 0):

It does work in general. The problem here is that angular 1 is not working nicely with webpack without a shim (see https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2049). Try this webpack loader config, it solved the issue for me, allowing use of ProviderPlugin with the same key as the module name:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        /*
         * Necessary to be able to use angular 1 with webpack as explained in https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2049
         */
        {
            test: require.resolve('angular'),
            loader: 'exports?window.angular'
        },
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'angular': 'angular',
    }),
],
```